Python dodecahedron to sphere image convertor
So I have this code that needs to move each pixel in the image to a new coordinate by using a formula which is
(R - sqrt(r^2 + d^2))(sin(arctan(r/d)))
That is needed to move an image from dodecahedrons surface to a sphere surface. The code is simple yet not performing as it needs to. If you think of it, it should return the same, but a little stretched image. But it doesn't. It returns an image of some acid trip. My deadline is really short and I could use any help you guys can think of <3
from PIL import Image
import math

R = 90
d = 50

def move_pixels(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    width, height = img.size

    new_img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), color="white")

    for f in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            
            new_width = 0
            new_height = 0

            if width%2==0:
                new_width = width+1
            else:
                new_width = width
            
            if height%2==0:
                new_height = height + 1
            else:
                new_height = height


            diff_y = new_height/2 - y
            diff_x = new_width/2 - f


            r = math.sqrt( math.pow(diff_y, 2) + math.pow(diff_x, 2))



            firstPart = (R - math.sqrt( math.pow(r, 2) + math.pow(d,2)))

            secondPart = math.sin(math.atan(r/d))

            x = secondPart*firstPart

            s = math.sqrt(2)

            dd = x/s

            yy = abs(round(dd + new_height/2))
            xx = abs(round(dd + new_width/2))
            
            if 0 <= xx <= new_width and 0 <= yy <= new_height:
                print(yy, xx)
                pixel_color = img.getpixel((f, y))
                new_img.putpixel((xx, yy), pixel_color)
    new_img.save("moved_image.png")

image_path = "img.png"
move_pixels(image_path)

Really thank you in advance guys <3

repost your code in the correct format and I would be happy to help

Did it bro. Sorry it took so long, my laptop gave me a blue screen while i was using Stack XD

Hi @MuradBagirli, and welcome to the StackOverflow community!!! Your question is quite interesting. However, to reproduce your problem, we need the img.png you are referring to.

@anmabe your suggested edit breaks OP's code. please retract it and review your suggestion.

@ChristophRackwitz, it should now be ok. I mis-indented the line new_img.save("moved_image.png"), but it now performs as the OP reports. Thanks for pointing that out!

There is something odd with your formula as is: d is a constant - so, while r will contain the distance from the image center to the pixel being evaluated (f, y), I see no calculation for the angle-declination of said pixel. (would be "theta" in most formulas) - all your formulas just take in  r and the constants R  and d - there is no way that would work.
